# How can I setup Laravel Vite to work with live refresh/reload when referencing vendor directory JS files?

Tags: laravel, vite

I have a Laravel 10 app that requires a bunch of Laravel packages I have built via composer. Whilst working locally I have all of these packages on the same level directory wise so composer can install them via their path and sets up symlinks.

This is great so that my package changes are reflected without having to constantly do composer updates.

At first I had a Vite build process per package and managed to get this working with live refreshing. However as my package library grew it got out of hand to have to be running 10+ vite dev servers.

I decided I could move my Vite build process to the Laravel app and then configure it to look in the vendor directory for each main JS file of each package. This worked, but only when running `npm run build`. If I run `npm run dev` I get issues with node modules.

**Here is my vite.config.js of my Laravel app:**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: [
            'flowbite',
            'alpinejs',
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'vendor/foobar/dashboard/resources/js/dashboard.js',
                'vendor/foobar/customer-portal/resources/js/customer-portal.js',
                'vendor/foobar/payments-stripe/resources/js/payments-stripe.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
            valetTls: 'foobar.test',
        }),
    ],
});
```

**And here is the start of, as an example, my dashboard.js file:**

```
import {initFlowbite} from "flowbite";
import Alpine from "alpinejs";
```

Again, `npm run build` and I have no issues. `npm run dev` and I get the following when accessing a page that loads my dashboard.js file:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "flowbite". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I've tried playing with optimizeDeps both include and exclude. Changing paths of how the node modules are referenced etc, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try `server.watch` option:

https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-watch

Probably Laravel ignores `vendor` so you could override this with `!`:

```
server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ['!**/vendor/foobar/**/*.js'],
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't help.